# Loop through same div' class and grab text using python webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I done all with selenium and webdriver and now not sure how to get text from ALL `div class Text3`. But also I have problem with `div id="TableStart_00023"` That changes now and then numbers "TableStart_00023, TableStart_0283 etc.."

**Here is HTML PART OF CODE**

```
 <div data-reactroot="" id="TableStart_00023">
    <ul>
        <li class="FirstRow03">
            <a class="aClass">
                <div class="innerCl">
                    <div class="Text1"></div>
                    <div class="Text2"></div>
                    <div class="Text3">Wanted data</div>
                    <div class="Text4"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="FirstRow02">
            <a class="aClass">
                <div class="innerCl">
                    <div class="Text1"></div>
                    <div class="Text2"></div>
                    <div class="Text3">Wanted data 2</div>
                    <div class="Text4"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is Python PART OF CODE what I done**

```
for content in driver.find_elements_by_id('TableStart_00023'):
    mytext= content.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="Text3"]').text
print(mytext)
```

How can I create loop thought all `div class Text3` and get text, when ID TableStart changes numbers? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath will return all elements `div class Text3` from your table:

`//div[starts-with(@id,'TableStart')]//div[@class='Text3']`

When you have all this elements (using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`) you can get texts from they.